# How To Render <Componet/> or Jsx multiple times based on Click or Form Submit

Tags: reactjs

I need to display this jsx again on my screen after everyClick  by following this approach, on console log the data is pushing successfully on the array but its not getting displayed on screen .

```js
const ExemptIncomeDetails = (props) => {
    var count = 0
    var [renderedcomponent, setRenderedComponent] = useState([])
    var data = []

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        data.push(
            <Row>
                <Column style={{ width: '3px' }}>1.</Column>
                <Column>
                    <SelectField size='sm ' />
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Input size='sm' />
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <Input size='sm' />
                    </form>
                </Column>
                <Column>X</Column>
            </Row>
        )
        setRenderedComponent(data)
        count = count + 1
        // TaleComponet.push(count)
        console.log('object', renderedcomponent)
    }

    const component = (
        <Row>
            <Column style={{ width: '3px' }}>1.</Column>
            <Column>
                <SelectField size='sm ' />
            </Column>
            <Column>
                <Input size='sm' />
            </Column>
            <Column>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <Input size='sm' />
                </form>
            </Column>
            <Column>X</Column>
        </Row>
    )

    return (
        <Grid item xs={12}>
            <div className='card' style={{ width: '100%' }}>
                <HeadingIcon title={'Details of Exempted Income(Including Minor Children,Interest Income,Divident Income etc.)'} />

                <Table>
                    <Row>
                        <Column style={{ width: '3px' }}>slnum</Column>
                        <Column align='center'>Nature Of Income</Column>
                        <Column align='center'>Description</Column>
                        <Column align='center'>Amount</Column>
                        <Column align='center'></Column>
                    </Row>

                    <Row>
                        <Column style={{ width: '3px' }}>1.</Column>
                        <Column>
                            <SelectField size='sm ' />
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <Input size='sm' />
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                                <Input size='sm' />
                            </form>
                        </Column>
                        <Column>X</Column>
                    </Row>

                    {renderedcomponent.map((item) => {
                        <>{item}</>
                    })}
                </Table>

                <hr />
                <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>
                    Total Gross<Input size='sm' style={{ marginLeft: '12px' }}></Input>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Grid>
    )
}

export default ExemptIncomeDetails
```

Answer (score 0):

For what I can see, this does not do anything:

```js
{renderedcomponent.map((item) => {
    <>{item}</>
})}
```

Change the `{}` to `()` to make it an expression, so this can actually return the elements:

```js
{renderedcomponent.map((item) => (
    <>{item}</>
))}
```

Or add a `return`:

```js
{renderedcomponent.map((item) => {
    return <>{item}</>
})}
```